# How to find out how DNS is resolved on client computer?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7

On a windows 7 client, when I ping a LAN host MYSTERY, it gives me the correct IP. However, when I do nslookup MYSTERY, it says non-existent domain. I checked both the DNS listed in ipconfig and find that the hostname MYSTERY is indeed not listed. The DHCP server also does not have the entry. The same behaviour occurs after I do ipconfig /flushdns. There in no entry in the local windows host file as well.

How can I find out where the client is getting the resolved IP?

Note: MYSTERY is a Synology Rackstation configured to join the network domain.

Comment: It seems like the `GetAddrInfoEx` function in Windows 7/8 could indicate what namespace provider is resolving a hostname. However, I don't actually know of any tool that uses this call and identifies the providers of any results. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Have you checked /windows/sistem32/dirvers/etc/hosts?

Comment: @madalinivascu host file checked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Windows machine must have some sort of mDNS resolver ([Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29)), let it be from iTunes, Skype, or other software that installs a mDNS resolver.  `ping` will resolve correctly if a resolver is installed because [LLMNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) is now used in Windows Vista and above.  LLMNR utilizes the mDNS resolver to return the record.

Synology uses a daemon called avahi, this is a [Multicast DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)/mDNS/DNS-SD server.  From the factory, Synology comes out of the box with it configured as "RackStation" or hostname from what I have experienced.

If you have a Mac, `dns-sd -B` will show you multicasted services.  You will see _http._tcp.local. service listed for RackStation.

`dns-sd -G v4 RackStation.local` should give you the proper IP address for your RackStation

`dns-sd -L RackStation _http._tcp.` should return all the information of the service, this includes port numbers, serial, model, etc

This also applies to DiskStation as well.  I did my testing on a DiskStation.  RackStation should be the same.

Comment: This is a bit of a non-sequitur as things stand, since `ping` doesn't resolve mDNS. If you're trying to answer a different question than the one that is being asked, can you preface this with the question that you *are* answering?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/624760

Comment: Well, I'll be damned. It's a little non-intuitive that this detail isn't easy to find in the documentation for getaddrinfo and associated headers. Thank you.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the information from that link.  No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

(This answer is probably wrong. @xeon seems to be on the right track and I've learned something here.)

---

The reason a DNS lookup fails is because ping isn't using DNS to resolve that name.

`nslookup` is a command for DNS lookups. `ping` on the other hand will also attempt to use [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS)/[WINS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service) and the [hosts file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) for name resolution. The most likely scenario is that this name was obtained via the former.

You can use `nbtstat -c` to list the NetBIOS names and IP addresses that have recently been seen, or `nbtstat -a <device>` if you want to actively search for a name. Keep in mind that `-a` will take longer as it has to attempt this once per interface. (you can't tell it to skip broadcast/only use WINS)

The `-r` option will let you compare what was resolved via broadcast with what was resolved via WINS, but that's getting a little more advanced.

Comment: How about accessing with `http://MYSTERY` through the web browser? Is it DNS?

Comment: nslookup the FQDN.  See if that works.

Comment: It will work for the browser because the standard [getaddrinfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call on the Windows platform includes results from WINS. (search that page for "netbios") There is no special coding required inside the web browser to support these names. `nslookup` on the other hand implements its own DNS lookup routines and is *purely* a tool for DNS resolution.

Comment: FQDN is the same behaviour. Ok, then why only that particular Windows client can ping and the other clients in the LAN cannot? Can I have some search keywords to find out how to check WINS/NETBIOS records in the Windows Server environment, please?

Comment: `nslookup` was designed as a DNS diagnostics tool. It never advertised itself as a tool that will perform other kinds of name resolution. :) Regarding the rest, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your windows [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file to make sure you do not have an entry hard coded there. This will force name resolution even if it is not resolvable there.